# Focus changes when returning to home world

Tags: the-strange

If I return to homeworld after having found a draggable focus, do I get the chance to keep the draggable focus? Or is it a recursion change-specific feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-checking the rules I couldn't find anything hat specifically contradicts that possibility. As long as the focus is compatible with the target world and the GM doesn't say otherwise, you should be able to keep it.